# Spanish language of my custom component is not working

Tags: custom-component, language, translation

I have created English and Spanish language file for my Joomla component but when I trying to change Joomla default language then my Spanish language file not working or not overwrite . Please give me an suggestion, How I can fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the path of the spanish language file?

Answer (score 1):

Show us some code for Your language file.

Probably Your language file isn't loading. Go to Global Configuration > System > Debug Language > ON. Now You'll see which language files are loaded.